# Enum type used in switch case error

Tags: ios, objective-c, enums

I wrote following code in my app:

```
typedef enum{
    PasswordModeEnter = 1,
    PasswordModeSetNewPassword = 3,
    passwordModeVerify = 5,
    PasswordModeChange = 7,
    PasswordModeDisabled = 9
}PasswordModes;
```

And I instantiated an object named PasswordMode.

```
- (id)initWithPasswordMode:(PasswordModes *)passwordMode nibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.PasswordMode = passwordMode;
    }
    return self;
}
```

I got an strange error when I wrote following code:

```
switch (self.PasswordMode) {
        case PasswordModeChange:
            //do something
            break;

        case PasswordModeDisabled:
            //do something
            break;
        case PasswordModeEnter:
            //do something
            break;

        case PasswordModeSetNewPassword:
            //do something
            break;
        case passwordModeVerify:
            //do something
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
```

I got following error:

> statement requires expression of integer type.

what is the problem and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is with this

```
ProblemModes *
```

The * should be removed.

Answer (score 6):

PasswordModes is just an enum, your init method incorrectly indicates that it is a pointer. The init method signature should be as follows:

```
- (id)initWithPasswordMode:(PasswordModes)passwordMode nibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil;
```

Your property should be as follows:

```
@property (nonatomic,assign) PasswordMode passwordMode;
```

Comment: Also, for better code readability, you should change "PasswordModes" to "PasswordModeType".

Answer (score 4):

you should specify the type of the enum, also you might want to use the new enum syntax.

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, PasswordMode) {
  PasswordModeEnter          = 1,
  PasswordModeSetNewPassword = 3,
  passwordModeVerify         = 5,
  PasswordModeChange         = 7,
  PasswordModeDisabled       = 9
};
```

You can use it as follows:

```
PasswordMode mode = PasswordModeEnter;

switch (mode) {
  case PasswordModeEnter:
    break;

  ...

  case PasswordModeDisabled:
    break;

  default:
    break;
}
```

Comment: @AmirAbbasKashani see my edit, you must not be using it correctly. how do you create and assign the property?